# Delphi DLL to enhance C++ Project

Tags: c++, delphi, mfc, delphi-2009

I have inherited an old C++ (MFC) project and will have to add new functionality.
The new functionality will mostly not conflict with the existing C++ code, like additional dialogs etc.
Having limited experience with C++ MFC, I would very much prefer to do the additional functionality in Delphi, create a DLL and use the DLL in the C++ project.

I guess this is generally possible, similar to using C++ DLLs in Delphi?
Are there limitations on what can be done this way?

Comment: what kind of a functionality are we talking about? GUI based?

Comment: yes, GUI based. For example, a dialog that shows a graph from data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delhi if I recall my history should create Dll's happily.  See here '[Calling delphi DLL from MS Visual C++](http://www.esanu.name/delphi/DLL/Calling%20delphi%20DLL%20from%20MS%20Visual%20C.html)' for an example

Answer (score 2):

Basically, there are no issues. But if you're going to use dialogs and so on, your application will be using two frameworks, MFC and the VCL, and they may not play very well together.